# Неоднородные члены предложения

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-неоднородные-определения

*В вазе стояли крупные красные душистые цветы.*
Здесь прилагательные обозначают разные признаки: цвет, форму, запах. Их считают неоднородными.
Но если я их произношу с интонацией перечисления, подчеркивая, что перечисляю восхитительные качества этих цветов, можно ли между ними поставить запятые?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• Я думаю, что можно поставить запятые.
Текст художественный, и если автору хочется отметить, что цветы безмерно восхитительны (прекрасны, шикарны), то однородность определений вполне оправданна.

> Согласованные определения являются однородными: <...>
> 3) если в условиях контекста, характеризуя предмет с разных сторон, объединяются каким-либо общим признаком (внешним видом, сходством производимого ими впечатления, отнесением к отдаленному общему понятию, причинно-следственной связью и т. д.): <...>
> *Вода струится по камешкам и прячет **нитчатые, изумрудно-зелёные** водоросли* (Сол.) — общее внешнее впечатление...

•• Примеры из Нацкорпуса

*Ветхая избушка сторожа, огромные яблони, красные сладкие арбузы, **желтые, душистые** дыни* (Н. И. Ильина. Дороги и судьбы).

*Слезы блеснули в прищуренных глазах Чукарина, по полному, загорелому лицу сетью растянулись мелкие морщины, русые большие усы приподнялись, сверкнули под ними **крупные, белые, чистые, ровные** зубы* (П. Н. Краснов. Ложь).

*Низкий лоб его покрылся большими каплями, на скулах появились пятна, растрепанная борода, усы и все **крупное, красное** лицо пришли в величайшее возбуждение* (А. Н. Толстой. Приключения Растегина).

[Однородные и неоднородные определения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98)